# Maven Dependency on Repo Hosted on Git

Tags: git, maven, ssh

We are hosting a maven repository internally within our own git (not Github) repository. git clone works fine:

```
git clone ssh://git@coyote.acme.com/home/git/acme-mvn-repo.git
```

so we know that the ssh keys are setup correctly.

We have a project that depends on artifacts hosted in the the maven above repository. The pom.xml for this includes:

```
<repository>
    <id>acme-repo</id>
    <url>ssh://git@coyote.acme.com/home/git/acme-mvn-repo.git</url>
</repository>

...

<!-- This dependency is in coyote.acme.com/home/git/acme-mvn-repo.git -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>coyote.acme.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>anvil</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

...

<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

When executing:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

we get:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for coyote.acme.com:anvil:jar:1.0.0: 
Could not transfer artifact coyote.acme.com:anvil:pom:1.0.0 from/to acme-repo
(coyote.acme.com:anvil): No connector available to access rep
ository repo (coyote.acme.com:anvil) of type default using the available factories
WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

Is there a different connector that we should be using?

Comment: Is this [tag:Windows] or [tag:Linux], if its Windows you will need to apply extra settings to tell Maven where to pick up the `SSH` public key - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

Comment: Windows for developers, but then also get built on linux via Jenkins.

Comment: Additionally on the `wagon` website - http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ssh/ . Download from `SSH` is not tested. Whilst, this does not answer your question - so apologies - Usually what I have done with several teams is host a Nexus repository - http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ and upload & download artifacts easily via Maven. Haven't come across as yet a SSH server to distribute dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to sonatype. I took a look and it looks neat, but for now I've gotten it to work by hosting the repo on tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven expects the server to give it single files. A git repo is just a collection of changes which need Git tools to make some sense of them. So what you do doesn't make sense and will never work.

What you can do: You can clone the repo on a HTTP server. Configure it to make the root folder accessible from web browsers. When this works, you can simply use the same URL in Maven.

I suggest to try to get this to work in a web browser first, because it will give you better error messages and you can use the mouse to browse the Maven repo.

Comment: There are plenty of people doing things like this using Github as a maven repo. See: http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/. The only difference that I can see is that we are using our own git instance rather than Github.

Comment: Github is (among other things) also a HTTP server. A naked Git repository that you access via SSH isn't. If you look closely at the URLs in the article that you linked, then you can see that all accesses happen via `https://...` and not SSH.